# Show certain worksheets, hide the rest

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to show worksheets from a list (Background Tab), but then hide the rest.  The below VBA works, but it can be shorten. I tried For i=1 etc. but to no avail.  Anyone can shorten this VBA?

Sub Sheets_Hide()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC4").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC5").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC6").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC7").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC8").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC9").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC10").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC11").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC12").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC12").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC12").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC13").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC14").Value Then
  If ws.Name <> Sheets("Background").Range("AC15").Value Then
  ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden

  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
```

Next ws

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Sheets_Hide()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not Worksheets("Background").Range("AC4:AC15") _
                .Find(ws.Name,LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End IF
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**OR**

```
Sub Sheets_Hide()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Worksheets("Background").Range("AC4:AC15") _
               .Find(ws.Name,LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End IF
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Not sure why the OP value in cell **AC12** is being tested three times. Perhaps a mishap with: copy and paste paste paste ... modify modify modify ....

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Wow, so succinct, awesome!!

Comment: The second one works perfect!!  I switched Hidden vs Visible, but in any case, works fantastic, omg you saved me so many lines of coding, thank you very much!!

Comment: your welcome and in that case, please mark answer as accepted solution.

Comment: How to "accept" the solution?  I'm flipping through the screen here and cannot find a button that says "accept"...??  Please let know?  Thank you again so much!!

Comment: [To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is my first week to use StackExchange, so thank you again!!